# Do outgoing SMTP servers need to have assigned domains?

Tags: smtp, domain, spam

Do outgoing SMTP servers need to have assigned domains?

If a domain name is not assigned to an outgoing SMTP server will it increase the spam score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Many sites will reject mail from you if your mail servers IP address does not resolve to a hostname.

Comment: According to RFC2821, it is not required. It's helpful, but not required.

Comment: Helpful is an understatement.

Comment: the SMTP RFC does not sufficiently explain the complexities of an SMTP server in the real world.

Comment: Well it's not its' purpose to explain those complexities. It's purpose is to define a standard. How that standard is implemented is up to software developer.

Comment: Spending 5 minutes reading an RFC does not make you an expert on SMTP.  My answer is 100% correct.  If your SMTP server does not have a hostname you WILL have problems.  I did not say "every site", I said "many sites".  Your insistence on arguing over what the RFC says is detrimental to the person answering the question.  At the end of the day, it doesn't matter what the RFC says, it matters what mail servers actually do. What mail servers do, is reject mail from addresses that don't resolve.

Comment: Justin is correct, many sites will reject based on lack of PTR (AOL domains when I last looked, for example). You can use any arbitrary  checks and weightings on an MTA to determine if you want to accept mail and still remain RFC compliant.

Comment: @Justin: I hear you but that wasn't the question that was asked. The question asked was "Is it required?" and the answer is no. You're correct that it can cause problems, but the OP didn't ask that. I'm not picking a fight I'm just answering the question that was asked: Is it required? No, it's not. The next question the OP should ask is "Can it cause problems if it doesn't?". The answer to that is yes, as you've stated. The best answer would have been a combination of your answer and mine: No, it.s not required but here's what can happen if it doesn't..."

Comment: I'm upvoting this to counter the downvote, which is unwarranted. The way I read the question it's not about standars, just what is required in the real world. The sad fact is that an great many system, either directly or indirectly via block lists, do reject email from systems without a matching DNS entry and it most certainly will increase the spam score in many, if not most, systems.

Comment: Part of any IT specialist's interaction with people and, dare I say it, end users, is to find out the real question instead of strictly answering the one brought forward ^^

Answer (score 3):

They don't *need* to have them per any standard in existence - however, as any mail admin with any experience would be able to tell you, a **vast** amount of anti-spam systems **do** use the lack of a reverse record as a reason for negatively scoring an SMTP relay.

Which means, the answer to the question in your title is - generally, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required as far as I know, but it can help.

Comment: very ambiguous answer.. domains cost money so I need to know for sure. but thanks anyway!

Comment: No, they're not required, but as joeqwerty said, they're *very* helpful. They don't need their own domain - they can be assigned a subdomain (e.g. smtp-out.example.com). If the forward and reverse dns for your SMTP servers don't match, the mail has a very high probability of getting tagged as spam.

Comment: How is it ambiguous? You asked what I interpreted as a yes or no question and I gave you a yes or no answer. No, they are not required as far as I know. It is helpful in order to keep you off of blocklists, but it's not required. If you'd like yo know for sure then read RFC2821, which is what I did and I don't see anything that implies that an assigned domain is required.

Comment: thanks guys, actually assigning it to a subdomain is the solution here...